# Excel - Transposing and Matching or VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel

Hoping someone can help... current Excel data set looks like this:

[Current Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHMSC.png)

[Desired Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLPXz.png)

Column 1 data needs match-up one-to-one to the data in Columns 2-7.
Column 1 data stays in Column 1, but Columns 2-7 data is moved to Column 2.

Not sure if I should go the INDEX route, TRANSPOSE or VLOOKUP... looking for a point in the right direction please.

Thanks so much...

Comment: What have you tried so far fam?

Answer (score 0):

Static solution:

1. Copy original range.
2. Go to your destination sheet, then Paste>Transpose

Dynamic solution:

Select your destination range, then enter as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
{=Transpose(sourceData)}
```

That way if you update the original data, your transposed table will update automatically.

Comment: Thank you, I'll work on your suggestion.. just so you know I've been working and researching how to manipulate this data for over two days. I used XSLT to extract the data - at first tried tweaking the XSLT to render the data correctly.  Then tried manipulating in Xpath using joins, even uploaded to Access, now finally into Excel.  Sometimes a newbie like me doesn't know how to asked the right question to gather research needed, but I'm trying to learn.  Thank you for the point in the right direction...